# LaTeX produces lines containing only a point in the bibliography

Tags: line-breaking, citing, natbib

If citations have a distinct length, the automatically set point at the end of the citation appears in the next line:

[image]

I am using `natbib` with bibiographystyle `agsm` for my references. Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}

I want to cite these guys \citep{guys2015}.

\bibliography{literature}

\end{document}
```

and my `literature.bib`:

```
@Article{guys2015,
author = {AutorA, A. and AutorB, B. and AutorC, B. and others},
title = {{Title of the reference Title of the reference Title of the reference Title of the reference Title of the reference Title of the r}},
journal = {{Journal name}},
year = {2012}
}
```

the geometry is required and I can not change the name of the reference, obviously. How can I make LaTeX printing this point at the end of the second line to avoid lines consisting of only one point in my references?

Comment: The `bbl` file has `{\em {Journal Name}} .` which allows a break before the fullstop.  This is presumably because the designer expected you to specify a volume number and pages etc. as well for such entries, and didn't anticipate the name of the journal being the final item.

Comment: adding volume number and pages at the right place solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In such examples the `.bbl` file has

```
{\em {Journal Name}} .
```

which allows a break before the fullstop. This is presumably because the designer expected you to also specify a volume number and pages etc. for such entries, and didn't anticipate the name of the journal being the final item.  For example adding a volume number 
as in

```
@Article{guys2015,
  author =   {AutorA, A. and AutorB, B. and AutorC, B. and others},
  title =    {Title of the reference},
  journal =  {Journal name},
  volume =   12,
  year =     {2012}
}
```

produces a `.bbl` file with

```
\harvarditem[AutorA et~al.]{AutorA, AutorB, AutorC et~al.}{2012}{guys2015}
AutorA, A., AutorB, B., AutorC, B. et~al.  \harvardyearleft
  2012\harvardyearright , `Title of the reference', {\em Journal name} {\bf
  12}.
```

with no space between the last item and the fullstop.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}

I want to cite these guys \citep{guys2015}.

\bibliography{literature}

\end{document}
```